# Delphi still keep on memory and do not release, why?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

On my project, I am using inherited MDIChild forms from base form. My problem is about memory management. After release forms ( by FreeAndNil) with FormClose events, Delphi still keep on memory and do not release.

What should I do for that? MDI management different or what?

Comment: Please show complete code that demonstrates the problem and also describe how you are diagnosing a memory leak.

Comment: Freeing a form does not free any objects it may have created.  Your MDI children are likely not cleaning up after themselves.  Without code we can't help.  Learning to use FastMM will probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: @J... Only if the objects are created without an owner, and there is no destructor that frees them. But if the objects are created with an owner, then freeing the owner frees the objects. Most likely onur is using Task Manager and drawing erroneous conclusions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, I should have said : "does not *necessarily* free any objects it may have created."  There are still a myriad of other types that are generally not owned by anything, however, and that are in common use and which need to be explicitly freed.  In any case, FastMM is the clear solution here, I think; it can confirm whether it is a real leak and help track where it is.

Comment: How do you found out that? I'm pretty sure this Q is about misreading information from the windows task manager

Comment: @onur kose :  How do you know the memory is not released?

Comment: @onur Why ask a question and then leave? If you want an answer, hang around. The first hour after you ask is critical. Do you even care about this? If you can't make the effort to be here, it seems that you don't care.

Comment: Yes, I'am checking memory leak on Task Manager.

Creating MDI like that;

AFormClass := TFormClass(FindClass(FormName));
ADataForm := TBaseForm(AFormClass.Create(Application) as TBaseForm


Destroying like that;

action := cafree & freeandnil(form)


So, my real problem is, for example after a few hours using my software, it gives "Out of Memory" error...

Comment: Dear @David, dont be angry at me... You are right but i am at office and working on many different problems. Thank you to all who care of my problem and try to help me.

Comment: Well, you'll need to track down your leaks. Don't use task manager, that's the wrong tool. Get the full version of FastMM and use its leak detection.

Comment: Running out of memory is usually something you have to try hard to do -- you must have a large memory leak somewhere.

Comment: David, thank you, i will be use fastmm.

regards.

Comment: You should add "Action := caFree;" to your MDIChild Form's onClose event.

Comment: At your Project code insert this,

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it has something to deal with the children Forms, even when you terminate an application with several children forms open Delphi will free them without memory leaks. 
To get a hint of what's going on, at your Source Project's code insert this,

```
Begin
    ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:= DebugHook <> 0; 
     …
 end.
```

Run the application in the IDE, do something you usually do then close the application. Delphi will inform you the memory leaks it encounters and a hint of what it is.

I always use above line in my applications, when testing (debugging), Delphi informs about memory leaks on shutdown.